# Is it possible to connect a second external monitor via a USB 3.0 port to an HDMI display?

Tags: display

I have two external monitors, [HP VH240a](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05624169) and a [Lenovo T540p](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd100413) laptop. It does not have any HDMI ports and has only one digital display connection. I connected on monitor via the digital cable.

It does have a USB 3.0 port. I tried to connect the second monitor's HDMI via a video capture device but it would not display the installed program.

Comment: You would need to purchase a docking bay.  There isn't a way to do video over USB 3.0 with the hardware you have.

Comment: “I tried to connect the second monitor's HDMI via a video capture device but it would not display the installed program.” Why would you think a video capture device — a devices that captures video and sends it to the computer — would be able to display an image from the computer to the monitor?

Comment: Most video capture devices are passthrough - so, HDMI in and out, with USB out (acting as a webcam) ...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question: "Is it possible to connect a second external monitor via a USB 3.0 port to an HDMI display?"

Yes, that is possible. Any of these will works:

- A real external USB graphics card (receives data from the computer and outputs the signal for the monitor)
- A display link card (looks similar as the one above, but some of the work is already done in the computer)
- Either of these built into a docking station
- If your USB-3 port is USB-C form factor their might be additional signals on it. (USB-C connectors often have thunderbolt, USB and DisplayPort on them, and display port is graphics output)

What will **not** work is a USB device for graphic **input**.
A capture device is an input device.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC apparently has a VGA port - as does the model of HP monitor you have. Its probably simpler to just get a VGA cable, which ought to be fairly cheap, and plug it in between your monitor's VGA ports and HDMI ports. Sometimes simple is best.

IF you had a PC with a VGA output spare, *and* your monitor supported HDMI there's adaptors that convert from analog VGA to HDMI. They'd need a USB port for *power* since they' are active devices, but that would work.